# How do I make a bullet point in a Slack message?

Tags: formatting, slack

I would like to make a bulleted list in a [Slack](https://slack.com/) message.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [Slack's "Format your messages" page](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages):

> To create a list, use Shift + Enter to create new lines in your message, then add a number or a bullet (•) before each item.
>
> Tip: To add a bullet point (•) from the comfort of your keyboard, try Option + 8 on a Mac, or Alt + 7 on most Windows machines.

Comment: I found that for Windows, it needs to be Alt + 7 using the numpad 7

Comment: Doesn't work :( Can you provide an example in text?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka As andrewb above said, it has to be Alt + Numpad 7.

Comment: Doesn't work for me when using the webapp. What's the raw text representation of a bullet?

Comment: Curious: Mac Option + 8.  So it doesn't use markdown?  I wanted to use markdown in Slack.

Comment: `Ctrl+Shift+8` on linux like Hpsaturn said

Comment: On Windows laptops that don't have numpads, `Alt+Fn+7` can be used.  The `Fn` key can be used with any of `789UIOJKLM` to produce the equivalent of the numpad number keys.

Comment: Also, on Windows the bullet doesn't show up until _AFTER_ you release the `Alt` key when using `Alt`+ numpad `7`

Answer (score 9):

To add bullet points to a message using your keyboard:

> Mac:
> **Option 8 on a Mac**
>
> Windows:
> **Alt 7 on most Windows machines**
>
> GNU-Linux:
> **Ctrl+Shift+8**
>
> iMac Keyboard:
> **Shift+Option+8**

[Format Messages in Slack](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages#lists)

Answer (score 9):

To complement this thread, On GNU-Linux for add bullet points to a `Slack` message using your keyboard:

```
Ctrl+Shift+8
```

Comment: Note: That is the number 8 on the top row, not the keypad 8, at least in my case.

Comment: You can select a block of text and use this shortcut, to put a bullet in front of each line. (Works on Mac, too) https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/201374536-Slack-keyboard-shortcuts#-message-shortcuts

Answer (score 8):

For anyone coming into this thread in mid-2020, Slack no longer supports any type of markup list within the message body. Shortcuts (cmd+shift+7, cmd+shift+8) will not work either.

They do support ordered and unordered list types within a post. Here's the full reference for what works. => https://www.markdownguide.org/tools/slack/

Unfortunately, it seems the only way to get a list in the message body in 2020 is to use their WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: Actually you can also use the * to maka a bulleted list, but only if the WYSIWYG editor is enabled! At least that's how it is on Mac at the time of writing

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are correct, but adding the full answer from Slack website [here](https://slack.com/intl/en-il/help/articles/202288908-format-your-messages)

To format a list, begin your message with a number or a bullet. Type `shift+enter`  to create a new preformatted line.

---

### Desktop Shortcuts

- For numbers:

  - `cmd+shift+7` on Mac
  - `ctrl+shift+7` on Windows For
- bullets:

  - `cmd+shift+8` on Mac
  - `ctrl+shift+8` on Windows

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used the Windows program Character Map, found the bullet point, copied, and pasted.  A similar method is to search Google (Wikipedia returned first), then copy and paste.

Mine is an inferior method.

Comment: The quickest method for the way you work is the best. I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone needs **indented (nested) bullet lists** in Slack, here's a suggestion:

Add a custom emoji that's just a transparent image (ex: https://cdn.hipwallpaper.com/i/7/29/4Udi3l.png) and use it to indent your messages (if you want a bullet per se, you can always use another emoji like `:black_small_square:`)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's SHIFT + OPTION + 8 on my iMac keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bullet point (•) from the comfort of your keyboard, try 'Option 8' on a Mac, or 'Alt 7' (using the number pad) on most Windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

Actually all you need to do is typing

```
- someText
```

then it will automatically convert it to a bullet point list

or

```
1. someText
```

to start a numbered list

Comment: This *used* to work, but doesn't anymore (May 2020). I can see messages I typed back in Feb of this year where this worked, but now it doesn't. Grrrr....

Comment: @Chad This *does* work with the WYSIWYG editor. Type hyphen space at the beginning of a line, and it turns into a bulleted list item, and each newline (shift-enter) will start a new item.