# Slack multi-level bullet point or numbered list

Tags: text-formatting, markdown, slack

I've seen the thread on single bullet points [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1282510/how-do-i-make-a-bullet-point-in-a-slack-message/1282516#1282516) but can't seem to find a way to add a 2nd or any additional levels (i.e. automatic indentation). Is this not a feature? I've tried the standard TAB key, but no luck.

Edit:

One workaround I've found is to use an external true Markdown editor like [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/app#) to write the list/bullet points and then just copy and paste to Slack. This seems to work well until Slack decides to integrate Markdown.

Comment: this is quite important - imagine should be way but i'm in the same boat not having found it yet

Answer (score 12):

According to the [documentation](https://slack.com/intl/en-cz/help/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages) you can nest lists by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> four times:

```
* test
    * test nested
        * test nested nested
```

...becomes:

[image]

---

**Edit:** The reply above works when your [message formatting preference](https://slack.com/help/articles/360039953113-Set-your-message-formatting-preference) is set to **markup**.

If you didn't change your preference the way how to add more indent is to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the beginning of the indented line:

[image]

Comment: That answer is apprently outdated. The linked documentation now states that you should press TAB to indent a line. I tested it and it works.

Comment: TAB moves to the next GUI element in my case (Schedule for later) in my case. The fours spaces seems to work for me on version (4.26.1 64-bit) which is the most current on apt-get as of time of writing.

Comment: @topher217 That's odd. It works fine for me with TAB on 4.27.154 (Windows app). Four spaces does NOT work here. Mind you i don't see any asterisks or anything, i.e. I don't see markup source. I have a wysiwyg view when I author messages.

Comment: @topher217 Note: The TAB feature works only if your cursor is currently on a text row that is already a bullet list item, i.e. has a bullet to the left. So, think of TAB/shift+TAB as "indent/unindent current bullet list item". If you're on a regular text line, TAB will move focus to other controls.

Comment: @KjellRilbe, yep, it appears to work with TAB on 4.27.156 on Ubuntu as well now. I don't see this mentioned in the [release notes](https://slack.com/release-notes/linux), but glad to see it working now!

Comment: The behavior depends on the [Format messages with markup](https://slack.com/help/articles/360039953113-Set-your-message-formatting-preference) preference.

Answer (score 11):

Additional indentations are not currently supported by Slack. Slack provides a subset of formatting provided by markdown and other standards.

https://www.markdownguide.org/tools/slack/

[image]

Comment: The table in the guide is incorrect as it shows support Yes for list instead of showing Partial and explaining the limitation.

Comment: This is now outdated - see the other answers

Answer (score 0):

They've actually fixed this now. At least for macs.

Simply start the bullets, press shift + enter to move to the next line and then the tab button indents or shift+tab outdents.

[screen capture showing example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYpKw.png)