# Nested bulleted list in Slack

Tags: text-formatting, slack, bullets

Is there a way to do nested bulleted lists with the new Slack markdown / formatting tools?

E.g. I tried this

```
 * something
   * nested something
 * something else
```

but it **doesn't** render it as

- something

  - nested something
- something else

I couldn't find info regarding this on [their help page](https://slack.com/intl/en-sk/help/articles/202288908-format-your-messages)

Comment: Have you tried using `<ol>` to create an ordered list, then a `<li>`, followed by an `<ol>` to create a sub-list? Also, "Tip: When you copy and paste text in markdown from another source into Slack, you can quickly apply formatting by pressing  (Mac) or  (Windows/Linux)." So you could use a markdown editor to get your `<ol>` and/or `<ul>`

Comment: @spikey_richie I'm not sure what you mean. Can you use html tags in Slack messages?

Comment: Those aren't HTML tags, they're markdown. https://www.markdownguide.org/basic-syntax/

Comment: Actually, scrap that. My bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slack multi-level bullet point or numbered list](https://superuser.com/questions/1483835/slack-multi-level-bullet-point-or-numbered-list)

Comment: September 2021 answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1672619/294269

Answer (score 43):

#### February 2021 update:

[Slack officially added support for indented lists](https://slack.com/intl/en-sk/help/articles/115004846068-Slack-updates-and-changes)

> **Format your messages with indented lists**
>
> When formatting your messages in Slack, you can now indent up to five
> lines in ordered and bulleted lists. ...

[image]

---

As a **workaround**, I turned off automatic formatting - since it irritated me anyway - and then I can use the plain old

```
* something
  * nested something
* something else
```

which renders with asterisks as it appears here - but since I need the nested structure more than the fancy bullets, it's better than nothing.

EDIT: ‍♂️ I just realized you can very simply do this using the actual bullet • character

```
• something
  • nested something
• something else
```

it will look pretty good in Slack too:

[image]

Inserting the • character is very simple using Compose key on Linux:

```
<Multi_key> <period> <equal>            : "•"   enfilledcircbullet # BULLET
```

(`AltGr` + `.` + `=`)

Comment: Combine your answer with Giuliana's answer and everyone is happy! :D

Comment: @AdrianLynch I just realized there's even simpler way :D edited my answer, without the need of emojis

Comment: For Mac users, the command is `⌥ + 8` to type a bullet point character.

Comment: For windows it's Alt + 0149 on the numpad.
If you don't want to disable auto-formatting on slack, you can place the char, space, then Ctrl+Z. Or use an AutoHotkey script to do all that, and use any custom shortcut you want for the job, including adding spaces in the beginning (something like a second-level slack bullet shortcut)

Comment: Windows users, try [WinCompose](http://wincompose.info/) for similar any-special-character-typing capabilities.

Comment: @SgtPooki  Thanks for that tip about the Alt-8 for mac! Made my morning. Better than coffee!

Answer (score 18):

Tabs did not work for me as of the time of this posting. I use the "Format messages with markup" option in Slack so I don't have the text formatting toolbar.

I can't even add a tab character, as it just moves cursor focus to the send button. I copy/pasted tabs in, and that didn't seem to work either, but I found an obvious solution.

Just add four spaces in front of the `*` to indicate nested lists. For example:

```
* item
    * nested 
        * nested nested
```

Results in:

[image: Slack nested list example]

Comment: This works best, and I think should be the best answer to address the original question if you don't want to use hacks and don't want to turn off markup.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a suggestion for indented messages in Slack:

Add a custom emoji that's just a transparent image (ex: https://cdn.hipwallpaper.com/i/7/29/4Udi3l.png) and use it to indent your messages (if you want a bullet per se, you can always use another emoji like `:black_small_square:`)

[image]

Comment: wow nice, that's a pretty cool workaround 

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to do nested bulleted lists with the new Slack markdown / formatting tools?

No official way, but hopefully soon. https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/1247310565493616653 ([mirror 1](https://archive.vn/jc1s9), [mirror 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20200904192133/https://twitter.com/slackhq/status/1247310565493616653)):

> We don't support nested bullets at the minute [...], but we're hoping to support nested bullet points properly in future.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a post, you can have nested bullet lists.
You need tor press `-` or `*`, then `<TAB>` key to increment your level:

[image]

Unfortunately, it does not work with messages.

Answer (score 1):

## 2022 update

#### One way:

1. Type an asterisk <kbd>*</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>space</kbd>, then
3. press <kbd>tab</kbd>

#### Another way:

1. Create a bullet point:

[image]

2. Press <kbd>tab</kbd> to indent it

#### Notes

- The indent must be created ***before*** adding text to the bullet
- Information from [here](https://slack.com/intl/en-au/help/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages-Format-your-messages)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding :blank: emoji and :dot: emoji
I've set this up in two minutes:
[image: my-custom-slack-nesting]

---

blank image^^^ (can you see it???)
[image: There-is-a-blank-image-here]

---

Dot image^^^
[image]