# Can I use an asterisk to make a bullet point in a Slack message?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, markdown, slack, bullets

**tl;dr** *Can I use Markdown's asterisk symbol (`*`) to make a bullet point list in Slack? Slack's [documentation](https://slack.com/intl/en-pl/help/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages) says that yes. But it is the only source where I found this. And this simply isn't working in my case. So, is or isn't asterisk supported in Slack?*

---

It seems that all answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1282510/156554) says about using an actual bullet character to make a bullet point in a Slack message? I.e. using as weird keyboard shortcut as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>. None of them says about using an asterisk (`*`) to achieve the same.

While Slack's [documentation](https://slack.com/intl/en-pl/help/articles/202288908-Format-your-messages) does:

[image]

Slack's documentation is in this case the only source that claims that asterisks works. But, whenever I put them into Slack message...

[image]

I am getting... asterisks and no bullet point lists.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this will be helpful, but the asterisk seems to be working for me. Make sure you are typing the asterisk character (*) then a space, then after the first bullet return to get a new line. What device/version of slack are you using?